# Substitute one character in a line only if it occurs before another specific character

Tags: regex

I have an instance where certain URLs are getting malformed with equal signs and I need to be able to remove them.

An example broken URL:

```
http://www.go=ogle.com/search?ie=UTF
```

to be corrected to this:

```
http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF
```

It can not simply replace the first occurrence of `=` because not all URLs are broken like this.

Is there a sed/awk or other regex way of deleting all instances of `=` only if they occur before a question mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>use</strike>

```
sed -e 's~\(http://[^?]*\)=\([^?]*\)~\1\2~'
```

which basically says to strip one = character from within anything starting with `http://` and then having anything but a `?`.

**edit** looking at it again, this is a lot cleaner:

```
sed -e 's~\(http://[^/?]*\)=~\1~'
```

Comment: I would describe that differently, but that's pretty much what I would use.  Didn't know you could use ~'s in place off / though.  I would say that you 'replace any string starting with http://, ending with =, and having no ?'s with the original string, not including the =.'

Comment: @slartibartfast: I updated the answer to (almost) match your description ;-)

Comment: as for ~ and /, some (most?) regexp environments let you choose the delimiter on the fly.